# use create-react-app with php index

Tags: php, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

i want to start new react project using great create-react-app tool, but i need to serve app using php to allow me to fetch some dynamic data and configuration and feed it to react before it starts.

how can i config create-react-app to server php ?

php have its own builtin server, so may be we can use it to launch index.php

```
php -S localhost:8000 ./public/index.php
```

is there a way to let webpack launch php built-in server and still have all live reload and features that comes with react-create-app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code:

1. Open your application folder in command line.
2. Write below code with your react config file. (E.g: development.config.js)

**Code**

```
webpack-dev-server --progress --inline --hot --port 8080 --config reactconfig/development.config.js
```

OR

```
npm start
```