# I need run create-react-app with file index.php instead of index.html because I have logic php that I will send to Javascript

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

Execute `npm run eject` and rename index.php to index.html, but it does not work. I need to include a class inside index.php to use a function that converts data encrypt to send toward React.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use create-react-app with php index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44693665/use-create-react-app-with-php-index)

Comment: Are you using any php server to serve that index.php file? Did you rename index after running build?

Answer (score 0):

Add an `.htaccess` and an additional `index.php` file to the `/public` directory of the app. Load `index.php` with apache, then require create-react-app's `index.html` file from PHP.

.htaccess

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

index.php

```
<?php

// PHP logic here

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/index.html');
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution,

First, execute:

```
npm run eject
```

then, change the code in paths.js to:

```
appHtml: resolveApp('public/index.php')
```

and webpack.config.dev.js (agree |php):

```
exclude: [/\.(js|jsx|mjs|php)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/]
```

after:

```
npm start
```

this works well

Comment: Raise the server, but do not read the php code, I'm testing with webpack-php-loader

Comment: Those things won't work. You need a proper php server to run that, i.e: apache, nginx or something like that with php active. Webpack won't solve that problem for you. You'll have to build your project and then copy to where those servers can read your file.