# React app wont allow PHP after switching index to a PHP file

Tags: php, reactjs

I've been coding in PHP for a few years and feel that ill be able to provide a more secure login and registration with that rather then in Reactjs.

I followed the answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52372211/i-need-run-create-react-app-with-file-index-php-instead-of-index-html-because-i) to switch my index.html to index.php.

Hosting the file works fine, but whenever I try to use PHP tags it gets commented out or printed directly as text. Any solution to this?

Comment: It sounds like your host isn't executing php files but is treating them as text - so the solution is dependant on which webserver you're using - apache, nginx, etc

Comment: @AdamHopkinson Ofc had to be somethign Ive overseen. Was so busy trying to make them work together I forgot that PHP still require the php libraries from apache. Tried starting only the reactapp. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome @Martin!